# border-radius у body

Tags: html, css, language-lawyer, border, overflow

Почему div не обрезался до круга? В аналогичном случае с другим контейнером всё обрезается. Причём, вроде как во всех браузерах такое поведение.

```css
body {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

```css
main {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<main><div></div></main>
```

Comment: На самом деле сложно ответить почему так происходит. С одной стороны, тэги `html` и `body` имеют ограниченное кол-во воздействий через css. С другой стороны, а почему бы и нет? В спецификации пока не удалось выяснить причину поведения, но, скорее всего, дело именно в кол-ве css-атрибутов, с помощью которых можно влиять на данные элементы.

Comment: действительно так ...интересно

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/WWoWZo - что у меня там жёлтого цвета ?

Comment: @MaximLensky, если для html не задан цвет, то он красится в цвет body. Тебе надо ещё `html { background: white; }` добавить и получится жёлтый круг с чёрной обводкой.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну таr то да ...а так то нет ... интересно

Comment: @Qwertiy а вообще работает для body width и height - смотри codepen

Comment: @MaximLensky, получается, если в мой пример добавить `html { overflow: hidden; }`, то div тоже обрезается. А почему так?

Comment: html то родитель а body его часть ...что бы обрезать body то мы должны обрезать html то есть родительский элемент ..по другому не получится так как каждый браузер смотрит на html и body по разному

Comment: так как решение всё же найдено - опубликовать мой ответ ?

Comment: @MaximLensky, ну опубликовать про `html { overflow: hidden; }` можно, но на вопрос "почему" это не отвечает.

Comment: @MaximLensky, _"что бы обрезать body то мы должны обрезать html то есть родительский элемент"_ - звучит очень сомнительно. К тому же, они же разного размера.

Comment: @MaximLensky, смотри https://jsfiddle.net/kyv4u32h/ - overflow:hidden на html влияет только на body, а на сам html не влияет.

Comment: @Qwertiy  ну даже по твоему примеру, смотри сам :https://jsfiddle.net/hpdon95e/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92187/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-maximlensky).

Comment: действительно интересно, а вот так обрезается : `html, body {...ваш css`

Answer (score 1):

Хороший вопрос.
Мне кажется дело в том, что `body` не может применить на себе некоторые свойства.
Если хочешь все `div` закруглить:

```css
    * div {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    div {
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background: black;
      color: white;
      padding: 50px;
    }
```

```html
  <div>
    1
    <div>
      2
      <div>
        3
        <div>
          4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Вроде как у меня такое даже в вопросе есть...